# `PlotLabel` for plots in a `Table`

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, labeling, labeled

I have a `Table` containing two plots, given by

```
Table[
 Plot[{Re[f[n]] /. j -> 3, Im[f[n]] /. j -> 3}, {n, 0, 15}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"Real", "Imaginary"}, 
  PlotLabel -> f[n]], 
{f, {Sum[Sinc[Pi*(#1 - i*j)], {i, 1, Floor[#1]}] & , 
   (-1 + E^(2*I*Pi*#1))/(j*(-1 + E^((2*I*Pi*#1)/j))) & }}
]
```

[image]

As you can see, Mathematica has rewritten the first `PlotLabel` (i.e.,`Sum[Sinc[Pi*(#1 - i*j)], {i, 1, Floor[#1]}] &`) into an expression it considers more useful or natural. I don't want it to do this. I want the `PlotLabel` for that plot to look like this:

[image]

i.e., as though it was written `PlotLabel -> "expr"`. But the other label is already how I want it.

I have experimented with using `StringForm` but it doesn't help. How do I do this? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Table[Plot[{Re[ReleaseHold@f] /. j -> 3,  Im[ReleaseHold@f] /. j -> 3}, {n, 0, 15}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 350, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Real", "Imaginary"}, 
  PlotLabel ->  f], 
{f, {HoldForm@Sum[Sinc[Pi*(n - i*j)], {i, 1, Floor[n]}], 
   HoldForm[(-1 + E^(2*I*Pi*n))/(j*(-1 + E^((2*I*Pi*n)/j)))]}}]
```

[image]

You can replace `HoldForm` and `ReleaseHold` with `Defer` and `First`, respectively, to get the same result.

As Bob Hanlon suggested in comments, in versions 12.0+ you can use `ReImPlot` as follows:

```
 Table[ReImPlot[ReleaseHold[f] /. j -> 3, {n, 0, 15}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 350, 
    PlotLegends -> "ReIm", 
    ReImLabels -> {"Real", "Imaginary"}, 
    ReImStyle -> {ColorData[97][1], {ColorData[97][2], Dashing[{}]}},
    PlotLabel -> f], 
  {f, {HoldForm@Sum[Sinc[Pi*(n - i*j)], {i, 1, Floor[n]}], 
      HoldForm[(-1 + E^(2*I*Pi*n))/(j*(-1 + E^((2*I*Pi*n)/j)))]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Also with version 12 you could use [`ReImPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReImPlot.html)

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon. Yes, I'm aware of `ReIm` but haven't found a way to make the two lines different colours!

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward -  Use the option [`ReImStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReImStyle.html)

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon. I updated with a version using `ReImPlot`.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you.